# is it possible to invert an black and white image using css?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an black and white image and i just need the inverse(black instead white and white instead of black) of that image. i know that it can be done with image editors,is there any possibility to deal it with css? is there any css property is available  to invert an black and white image?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have the `filter` property:

```
.yourImage{
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%); /* Safari/Chrome */
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

This will invert the colors as opposed to simply making the image black and white.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
```

Or just use `invert(1)` instead of `grayscale(1) invert(1)` if you have black and white image.

You can also use invert filter for ie like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(invert=1);
zoom: 1;
```

For more browser compatibility, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/373253) or [jQuery.BlackAndWhite](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
.yourimage {
       -webkit-filter: brightness(10);
       filter: brightness(10);
 }
```

And this worked for me